# Java: Date/Time from Database to milliseconds, hour disappearing

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

I am having an issue with Dates and timezones.

I have a MySQL InnoDB database which holds two fields `DATE(yyyy-MM-dd)` and `TIME(HH:mm:ss)`. These are known as to be `UTC (0 GMT)`. My computer is based in `CET (+1 GMT)`.

• `dateObject` is the result from this `resultSet.getTime("date_field")` ([java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html))

• `timeObject` is a result from this `resultSet.getDate("time_field")` ([java.sql.Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html))

In the database DATE is stored as `2014-02-22` and TIME `15:00`

```
System.out.println("Untouched "+dateObject+" "+timeObject);

long date = dateObject.getTime();
long time = timeObject.getTime();

System.out.println("Touched "+new Date(date+time));
```

Results in the following output:

```
Untouched 2014-02-22 15:00:00
Touched Sat Feb 22 14:00:00 CET 2014
```

Why is one hour being skipped off the Touched output? I was expecting the following:

```
Untouched 2014-02-22 15:00:00
Touched Sat Feb 22 15:00:00 CET 2014
```

To rumble things up I have tried with the following also:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(date+time)));
```

And result:

```
2014-02-22 14:00:00
```

All in all. I am expecting GMT+1 to show 16:00(local) and GMT+0 to display 15:00

Comment: because your machine is in a different timezone.

Comment: Could you elaborate, what I am doing is that I am taking apart the DATE and TIME objects and putting them back together, I am expecting them to be the exact same.

Comment: What does the `.getTime()` method do?

Comment: It retrives milliseconds from 1970 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is similar to this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604194/how-to-create-a-java-util-date-with-absolute-values-for-fields-without-timezone/21605551#21605551). But note following details about `toString()`.

```
java.util.Date.toString() => output dependent on your system time zone
                             in format pattern "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"

java.sql.Date.toString() => output in format "yyyy-MM-dd" (your dateObject)
java.sql.Time.toString() => output in format "HH:mm:ss" (your timeObject)
```

The sql representations are not dependent on time zone. So you compare apples and peaches.

**Supplementary remark:**

I have invested more in testing and found:

```
java.sql.Date dateObj = new java.sql.Date(2014 - 1900, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 22);
Time timeObj = new Time(15, 0, 0);
Time midnight = new Time(0, 0, 0);
Date d = new Date(dateObj.getTime() + timeObj.getTime());

System.out.println("dateObj: " + dateObj + "/" + dateObj.getTime()); 
// dateObj: 2014-02-22/1393023600000, one hour less than a full day because of UTC-long

System.out.println("timeObj: " + timeObj + "/" + timeObj.getTime()); 
// timeObj: 15:00:00/50400000 => one hour less as UTC-long

System.out.println("midnight: " + midnight + "/" + midnight.getTime()); 
// midnight: 00:00:00/-3600000 => one hour less, negative!

System.out.println(new Date(dateObj.getTime())); // Sat Feb 22 00:00:00 CET 2014
System.out.println(new Date(timeObj.getTime())); // Thu Jan 01 15:00:00 CET 1970
System.out.println(d); // Sat Feb 22 14:00:00 CET 2014
```

So I strongly suspect following effect: Both dateObject and timeObject are been calculated your system time zone, therefore their utc-long values show both one hour less - the time zone offset. If you combine both in one Date-object by just summarizing up then one of both deltas gets lost because one single date object cannot take in account two offsets.

Conclusion: You tried to combine date and time by summarize their utc-longs, but this is in general a faulty approach. **Date plus Date is not Date, but undefined**! In domain-specific language you can only add a duration/period to a date/time. So a solution having a midnight object could be:

```
Date d = new Date(dateObj.getTime() + timeObj.getTime() - midnight.getTime());
System.out.println(d); // Sat Feb 22 15:00:00 CET 2014, correct - what you wanted
```

Comment: I am cofused as I when I use this: SimpleDateFormat sdfFull = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); And hour is lost also.

Comment: So you are saying that because it's a difference between java.sql.Date /java.sql.Time an hour is skipped off?

Comment: @KarlMorrison You should also do `sdfFull.setTimeZone(...)` before applying it on your j.u.Date-object (touched version), otherwise you get again a timezone-dependent output different from the sql-variants.

Comment: I did indeed try that also, same error. TimeZone tzGmt =  TimeZone.getTimeZone("Gmt0"); with sdfFull.setTimeZone(tzGmt); results in 2014-02-22 13:00:00. It seems as GMT+1 is 14:00:00 and GMT+0 is 13:00:00 this is all fine except that the value in the database to start with is 15:00:00 :/

Comment: I am impressed! Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

I think I did answer ma question (Remember `timeObject` in the db is 15:00:00 at UTC):

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Gmt0");
SimpleDateFormat sdfFull = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdfFull.setTimeZone(tz);

Date updateDate = sdfFull.parse(dateObject.toString()+" "+timeObject.toString());

System.out.println(updateDate);
```

Results in what I was hoping for:

```
Sat Feb 22 16:00:00 CET 2014
```

Comment: Otherwise your new code seems to be okay therefore my upvote.

Comment: Your answer was indeed what I was looking for on the original question! the next step was trying to get my 15:00:00 GMT+0 database TIME object to jump to 16:00:00 at GMT+1. I understand it more now so danke! :)